Proof for Theorem 4.1. of Davis Direct Methods for Sparse Linear Systems
I am trying to learn about sparse Cholesky factorization and I've read the first two chapters of Davis Direct Methods for Sparse Linear Systems. The first two chapters are mostly clear.
Most of the theorems however are stated without proofs (at least where I am so far). And in Chapter 4, which is the one I am mostly interested for now we have the following:

Theorem 4.1 (Rose, Tarjan and Lucker [175]). The edge $(i,j)$ is in the undirected graph $G_{L + L^T}$ if and only if there exist a path $i \to j$ in the undierected graph of $A$ where all the nodes in the path except $i$ and $j$ are numbered less than $\min(i,j)$.

In my understanding

$L$ is the lower triangular factor of the Cholesky factorization
$G_A$ (for any square matrix $A$) is a matrix whose set of vertices contains a vertex per column and an edge iff $a_{ij} \neq 0$.

Therefore the theorem states a property for $L + L^T$.
Questions:

Why are we considering $L + L^T$?
What is the proof? The reference is Algorithmic Aspects of Vertex Eliminations on Graph but I cannot find such theorem. Also, for some of them, I don't see the proof either.


In the paper mentioned in the question it is assumed the matrix being studied is SPD. The Theorem 4.1. of Davis is not stated as presented in the referenced paper.
Rather it is the following

Lemma 3: Let $G_\alpha = (V,E,\alpha)$ be an ordered graph. Then $\left\{ v, w\right\}$ is an edge of $G_\alpha^* = (V, E\cup F(G_\alpha))$ iff there exist a chain $\mu = \left[v = v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_{k+1} = w \right]$ in $G_\alpha$ such that
$$
\alpha^{-1}(v_i) < \min(\alpha^{-1}(v),\alpha^{-1}(w)), \;\;\; 2 \leq i \leq k
$$

For notation I refer to the paper. The proof of the lemma is also clear. But if someone is curious I can just report the proof here.
